# How can I add a post to RainLab.Blog using my plugin?

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I want to take information from the RSS feeds and transfer it to the RainLab.Blog.
I have already created my own plugin
I don't understand how to trigger the action of the RainLab.Blog

Comment: you can simply use post modal `\plugins\rainlab\blog\models\Post.php`  => `$post = new RainLab\Blog\Models\Post();` assign all values and save it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$AllCategories = 2; // category id
$post = new Post();
$post->title = 'testSetPost';
$post->slug = 'testSetPost';
$post->content = '<h1>TEST SET POST</h1>';
$post->excerpt = '<h6>TEST SET POST</h6>';
$post->published_at = '2021-02-05 15:14:23';
$post->published = true;
$post->save();

$post->categories()->attach($AllCategories);

$file = new File;
$file->fromUrl('https://picsum.photos/500/320/?random=1','test-set-post' . '.jpg');
        
$post->featured_images()->save($file);
```